# Generate variable number of fields for a form

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am creating an application in flask using python. Now on a specific route, I need to ask user to enter a number and based on that number generate those many input fields on the same page.

I am only able to do it static wise. Dynamically I am unable to do so. I do not have experience with JS or Jquery if that is what it will take to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following tutorial to dynamically add a textbox and remove it. You might need to change the logic a bit to add user input and generate the textbox accodingly.

[Dynamically add/remove textbox in html](https://www.encodedna.com/2013/07/dynamically-add-remove-textbox-control-using-jquery.htm)